# Can't Figure Out The Reason UILabel Isn't Displaying The String Being Assign to It - Quote Quiz App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been following online tutorials over at raywenderlich.com, and came upon a little road block. In a tutorial ([Quote Quiz](http://www.raywenderlich.com/31814/objectively-speaking-2-a-crash-course-in-objective-c-for-ios-6)), I seem to have done something wrong because the strings, extracted from the Quote.plist, is simply not displaying on the question and answers labels.

Here is my view controller.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Quiz;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger quizIndex;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Quiz* quiz;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* questionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* answer1Label;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* answer2Label;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* answer3Label;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* answer1Button;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* answer2Button;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* answer3Button;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView* movie1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView* movie2;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView* movie3;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* statusLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* startButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* infoButton;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Quiz.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger answer;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.quizIndex = 999;
    self.quiz = [[Quiz alloc] initWithQuiz:@"Quotes"];
    self.questionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:238/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [self nextQuizItem];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) nextQuizItem {
    if(self.quizIndex == 999){
        self.quizIndex = 0;
        self.statusLabel.text = @"";
    }else if((self.quiz.quizCount-1) > self.quizIndex) {
        self.quizIndex++;
    }else{
        self.quizIndex = 0;
        self.statusLabel.text = @"";
    }

    if(self.quiz.quizCount >= (self.quizIndex+1)){
        self.questionLabel.text = self.quiz.quote;
        self.answer1Label.text = self.quiz.ans1;
        self.answer2Label.text = self.quiz.ans2;
        self.answer3Label.text = self.quiz.ans3;
    }else{
        self.quizIndex = 0;
        [self quizDone];
    }

    self.answer1Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:238/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.answer2Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:238/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.answer3Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:238/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    self.answer1Button.hidden = NO;
    self.answer2Button.hidden = NO;
    self.answer3Button.hidden = NO;
}

-(void) quizDone {

}
@end
```

And my Quiz.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Quiz : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSMutableArray* movieArray;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger correctCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger incorrectCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger quizCount;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString* quote;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString* ans1;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString* ans2;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString* ans3;

-(id)initWithQuiz:(NSString*)plistName;
-(void)nextQuestion:(NSUInteger)idx;
-(BOOL)checkQuestion:(NSUInteger)question forAnswer:(NSUInteger)answer;
@end
```

and Quiz.m:

```
#import "Quiz.h"

@interface Quiz()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* quote;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* ans1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* ans2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* ans3;
@end

@implementation Quiz

-(id)initWithQuiz:(NSString *)plistName {
    if((self=[super init])) {
        NSString* plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistName ofType:@"plist"];
        self.movieArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath];
        self.quizCount = [self.movieArray count];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)nextQuestion:(NSUInteger)idx {
    self.quote = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.movieArray[idx][@"quote"]];

    self.ans1 = self.movieArray[idx][@"ans1"];
    self.ans2 = self.movieArray[idx][@"ans2"];
    self.ans3 = self.movieArray[idx][@"ans3"];

    if(idx == 0){
        self.correctCount = 0;
        self.incorrectCount = 0;
    }
}

-(BOOL)checkQuestion:(NSUInteger)question forAnswer:(NSUInteger)answer {
    NSString* ans = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.movieArray[question][@"answer"]];

    if([ans intValue] == answer) {
        self.correctCount++;
        return YES;
    }else{
        self.incorrectCount++;
        return NO;
    }
}
@end
```

I am using the latest Xcode 6, the outlets are connected, and the plist file I am using has the name "Quotes.plist".

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done? Is the code in this clause, if(self.quiz.quizCount >= (self.quizIndex+1)), executed? Put a breakpoint on the last line in that clause, and inspect the labels and strings in the debugger.

Comment: Yes, the if clause is being executed, but I noticed that for some reason the self.questionLabel.text gets a nil value.

Comment: "some reason" - if the LHS of an assignment is set to `nil` in most cases that suggests the RHS is `nil`; track the RHS back to see when it becomes `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the next quiz question before displaying it.

Add the following to the second if statement of nextQuizItem in ViewController.m:

```
[self.quiz nextQuestion:self.quizIndex];
```

so that it looks like this

```
if(self.quiz.quizCount >= (self.quizIndex+1)){

    [self.quiz nextQuestion:self.quizIndex]; // <-- ADD THIS

    self.questionLabel.text = self.quiz.quote;
    self.answer1Label.text = self.quiz.ans1;
    self.answer2Label.text = self.quiz.ans2;
    self.answer3Label.text = self.quiz.ans3;
}else{
    self.quizIndex = 0;
    [self quizDone];
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I must have missed it. There was just no way the quote property could have contained its value without the proper initialization, which was present in that particular method. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If this solved your problem, please select it as the answer. Thanks!